# How should i format/set up my dataset/dataframe? and factor ->numeric problems

Tags: arrays, r, excel

New to R and new to this forum, tried searching, hope i dont embarass myself by failing to identify previous answers.

So i got my data, and i intend to do some kind of glmm's in the end but thats far away in the future, first im going to do some simple glm/lm's to learn what im doing

first about my data:
I have data sampled from 2 "general areas" on opposite sides of the country.

in these general areas there are roughly 50 trakts placed (in a grid, random staring point)

Trakts have been revisited each year for a duration of 4 years

A tract contains 16 sample plots, i intend to work on trakt-level so i use the means of the 16 sample plots for each trakt.

2x4x50 = 400 rows (actual number is 373 rows when i have removed trakts where not enough plots could be sampled due to terrain etc)

the data in my excel file is currently divided like this:

rows = trakts

Columns= the measured variable

i got 8-10 columns i want to use

short example how the data looks now:

V1 - predictor, 4 different columns

V2 - Response variable = proportional data, 1-4 columns depending on which hypothesis i end up testing,

the glmm in the end would look something like, (V2~V1+V1+V1,(area,year))

```
Area Year Trakt   V1               V2
A    2015   1     25.165651        0 
A    2015   2     11.16894652      0.1
A    2015   3     18.231           0.16
A    2014   1     3.1222           N/A
A    2014   2     6.1651           0.98
A    2014   3     8.651            1
A    2013   1     6.16416          0.16
B    2015   1     9.12312          0.44
B    2015   2     22.2131          0.17
B    2015   3     12.213           0.76
B    2014   1     1.123132         0.66
B    2014   2     0.000            0.44
B    2014   3     5.213265         0.33
B    2013   1     2.1236           0.268
```

How should i get started on this?

8 different files?

Nested by trakts ( do i start nesting now or later when i'm doing glmms?)

i load my data into r through the read.tables function

If i run: `sapply(dataframe,class)`
V1 and V2 are factors, everything else integer

if i run `sapply(dataframe,mode)`
everything is numeric

so finally to my actual problems, i have been trying to do normality tests (only trid shapiro so far) but i keep getting errors that imply my data is not numeric

also, when i run a normality test, do i only run one column and evaluate it before moving on to the next column or should i run several columns? the entire dataset?

should i in my case run independent normality tests for each of my areas and year?

hope it didnt end up to cluttered

best regards

Comment: You are asking several different questions at once. You'd have a better chance of getting answers by asking one at a time.
Have you tried the following?  `lapply(dataframe, function(f) { shapiro.test(as.numeric(f)) }`

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have made an additional question about my dataset, i found the solution so i can perform shapiro tests now